# Any software to image a drive and do partial restores?

Tags: windows-7

Not quite the standard *how do I make an image* question, so please bear with me.

I'm wanting to make an image (let's call it Image A) of my current windows partition, I then want to install things, modify files, etc. and then take another image of the same partition (called Image B). Further on down the line more things will be installed and modified, but I want to be able to tell the software to revert back to Image A, but keep all the modifications since Image B.

I'm ripping my hair out trying to find some software to achieve what I'm after.  Is there such a piece of software, or at least something that can do a similar job?

**Edit**: A little example:

1 - Original system state.

2 - Image A taken of system.

3 - File A added, File B modified, File C deleted.

4 - Image B taken of system.

5 - File D, E, F added, File B deleted.

I want to revert to Image A, but keeping the changes since Image B. Ideally, File D, E and F would remain. File A would be removed, File B would be reverted to the original state. and File C would be recovered. Yes, there would a conflict here as File B was deleted after Image B, although the restoration of Image A had a File B, but there's no reason I wouldn't have the option to choose between the conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Rollback RX](http://www.horizondatasys.com/169614.ihtml) I think it claims to be able to do something very close to what you want. My understanding is it keeps a record of your sectors and just always writes to "unused" sectors so that the data you've deleted/changed stays available for however long it is until it needs to re-use that particular sector. It's pretty interesting in theory, but I don't know how performance is affected, we're piloting it at work right now, I think.

> Roll-back, yet recover files from your "future" snapshot(s)

Comment: That looks as though it could do the job... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are asking for makes sense. Reverting to image a *means* that everyhing that happened since then will be lost. That is the intention.

If you are looking for something that can keep some modifications but not others, you will have to look at a different backup solution (probably something that can back up in diffs and lets you pick the point that you want to restore from exists, but off the top of my head I don't know of any) besides images.

Comment: Yes, true - that is generally the intention, but there is no reason why the above is not possible.

Comment: Sure it is. The way a backup by image works is it replaces all the bits on the drive with the bits in the image.